# KeystoneJS API on EC2 with loadbalancer, logs me out on refresh

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cookies, keystonejs

I have a web app with a KeystoneJS API. The webapp runs on Digital Ocean, the API is on an AWS EC2 instance with a load balancer (I had to add the load balancer to convert the API calls from https to http).
This all works fine, I can log in and use my webapp. But if I refresh the webapp I get logged out. I can't figure out why I get logged out on a page refresh. When running locally I don't see this behaviour.

I suspect this is related to the load balancer.

On the load balancer, I enabled Application based stickiness as per AWS docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html#application-based-stickiness

I set the App cookie name to 'keystonejs-session'